# Вопрос об округлении (round half to even)

Tags: java, float, double, binary, ieee-754

Объясните плиз эту таблицу и подписи к ней:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю: тут показан результат всех трёх режимов округления (вниз, вверх, к ближайшему) для четырёх вариантов двух отбрасываемых битов. Т.е. это таблица описания правил округления во всех трёх режимах. "-" в таблице означает усечение числа до ближайшего меньшего, "+" - увеличение числа до ближайшего большего, "-/+" - или первое или второе в зависимости от соглашения (обычно в зависимости от следующего слева бита - он должен стать нулевым).

Объясните мне плиз это все поподробней - особенно интересует round half to even, я не понимаю откуда комп берет значения sticky bits и в каком количестве - ведь чтобы округлять он должен знать эти sticky bits (причем в каком то количестве). Я также приложил фото страницы на которой говорится о sticky bits.

Вот она:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

> round half to even

Всё что меньше половины округляется в меньшую сторону, всё что больше половины - в большую. Остаётся сама половина - она округляется так, чтобы получилось чётное число.

Вспоминаем, что в компьютере двоичное представление информации. Значит половина - это единственная 1, за которой следуют только нули. Соответственно, она будет округляться таким образом, чтобы предшествующий ей бит стал нулевым. Если он уже был нулевым, то так и останется. Если же он был единичным, то происходит округление в большую сторону, т. е. к нему добавляется 1 и всё идёт по обычным правилам сложения.